# How to make jQuery UI Autocomplete so that when users starts typing other content goes modal?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like that when users start to use jquery UI autocomplete (element gets a focus, or a user starts to type), that other content (outside of the elements shown by autocomplete) looks like being under a modal window.

When the element loses a focus, other elements outside of autocompleter shall look normal.

Similar behavior is used by TripAdvisor (at this moment), you can see at TripAdvisor website that when users start typing in a search box, other content looks like being behind a modal window.

How to achieve that with jqueryUI?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to perform this functionality with the following:

**CSS**

```
#modal-background {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa; /* white */
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  opacity: .20;
  -webkit-opacity: .2;
  -moz-opacity: .2;
  z-index: 10; /* 1000 */
}


#modal-background.active {
  display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

put

```
<div id="modal-background"></div>
```

after the `<body>` tag

**Autocomplete JS code**:

```
jQuery('#your_autocomplete').autocomplete({
...
     open: function(event, ui) {
       $("#modal-background").addClass("active");
     },
     close: function(event, ui) {
       $("#modal-background").removeClass("active");
     },
...
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/adamovic/f4we9dbo/